# Extract contents of RPM into temporary directory in Python

Tags: python, rpm, temp

I'm writing a tool to verify RPMs in Python and print out the actual diffs in the files that changed.

I can fetch the RPMs from the ftp server with `ftplib`.  I was thinking of saving the rpm in `/tmp` and using `subprocess` module to run

```
rpm2cpio myrpmfile.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

to get the files in the RPM so that I can diff the files.  Afterwards, I'll delete the temp files.

It seems a bit hacky, so is this the best approach, or is there a more elegant solution with Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use one of the python `libarchive` interfaces, which support cpio files.  The main ones seem to be [libarchive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libarchive/) and [libarchive-c](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libarchive-c/).  RPM also comes with a python interface, but it appears to be considerably more work to get it to do what you want to do.

Comment: This seems to me more of a comment than an answer, particularly since the core of it is link only.

Comment: This still requires to first extract the cpio archive from the rpm archive. That is quite simple: [Here is the spec](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-file-format-rpm-file-format.html) and, maybe useful as a starting point, [here a hack'ish implementation I once wrote for personal use](https://github.com/phillipberndt/scripts/blob/5f006095c7bc9628f0811844c957bedbacd2a6ce/unpack/unpack#L366).